# Question about GPU usage in Google Colab when training Keras/TF models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have a quick question: when using Google Colab with the GPU enabled, does all of the code already run on the GPU then or is there some setting in the code that we must change to make it run on the GPU? Specifically, if I am training a neural network model in Keras/TF, do I need to edit my code in any way to ensure that the model is trained on the GPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as showed in the [Tensorflow with Gpu](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb) example notebook you can run your model in the following way to make sure it is running on the chosen device:

```
def gpu():
  with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  random_image_gpu = tf.random.normal((100, 100, 100, 3))
  net_gpu = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 7)(random_image_gpu)
  return tf.math.reduce_sum(net_gpu)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also wondering for the same thing. the inputs of my model are numpy.ndarrays should I convert them to tensors and move them to the gpu device or this happens automatically? Should I also move the model to the gpu device? Somewhere I have read that this happens automatically if you have enable gpu in colab. I am using keras from tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import HeNormal
```

For what is worth it I have notice that when I fit the model the gpu ram stays the same and the system ram increases which I think that it is an indication that I am not using gpu